# R and latex: Tabulating ranked data frame

Tags: r, latex, tabular

I generated a data frame that gives me that top n variables and their associated values by melting my original data frame and applying a ranking function. My ranked data frame looks like this:

```
   SysID     variable      value   Class1   Class2
1      1  S.noun_noun 0.13121019     Open     Open
2      1  S.verb_verb 0.12611465     Open     Open
3      1    S.det_det 0.04076433   Closed   Closed
4      1  S.verb_noun 0.03821656     Open     Open
5      1   S.prep_det 0.03312102   Closed   Closed
6      2  S.noun_noun 0.19791667     Open     Open
7      2  S.verb_verb 0.13750000     Open     Open
8      2    S.det_det 0.04375000   Closed   Closed
9      2    S.prn_prn 0.03958333   Closed   Closed
10     2 S.coord_prep 0.03750000   Closed   Closed
11     3  S.noun_noun 0.16730769     Open     Open
12     3  S.verb_verb 0.14615385     Open     Open
13     3    S.det_det 0.05384615   Closed   Closed
14     3 S.coord_prep 0.04423077   Closed   Closed
15     3  S.prep_prep 0.04230769   Closed   Closed
```

Now I'm trying to print it into a LaTeX document. I'd like it to look like this:

```
    1                   2                    …
    variable    value   variable    value   
1    S.noun_noun    0.13121019  S.noun_noun 0.19791667  
2    S.verb_verb    0.12611465  S.verb_verb 0.1375  
3    S.det_det  0.04076433  S.det_det   0.04375 
4    S.verb_noun    0.03821656  S.prn_prn   0.03958333  
5    S.prep_det 0.03312102  S.coord_prep    0.0375
```

I see that `tabular` from the `tables` package is potentially able to do this, but I can't figure out the correct formula to use. Can someone recommend either a tabular formula that can format the data in this format, or another package/function to use? Thanks for your help.

Comment: How about `do.call(cbind, split(df[2:3], df$SysID))`?

Comment: That's useful. If I do that, then my question reduces to how to tabulate the results in a latex table, so that each `df$SysID` appears as a main header and `variable` and `value` are subheaders.

Comment: Can't help with that, unfortunately.. But surely someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty manual way, so if your `SysID` is comprised of many levels, this might not seem like a viable option (before editing, I noticed your original `SysID` went up to 8). This assumes your data is in an object called `DF`, change appropriately:

```
g<-split(DF[,2:3], DF$SysID)
#here you merge them side by side
#note that the variable names are not right
#add a new row with SysID
ggg<- rbind.data.frame(c(g[[1]],g[[2]],g[[3]]))
gggnames <- c("variable 1", "value 1", "variable 2", "value 2", "variable 3", "value 3")
colnames(ggg) <- gggnames
stargazer(ggg, summary=FALSE)
```

This will output a `LaTeX` table for you to copy and paste.

The one line solution with this library offered in the comments by @docendo:

```
 stargazer( do.call(cbind, split(DF[2:3], DF$SysID)), summary=FALSE)
```

Again, `DF` is the object of the data.

If the table is too long, an `xtable` solution could also work. Again, taking from the comments and assuming the original SysID, which suggests that post-processing (removing the bottom from the first table and the top from the second table is the most likely solution to have it in one table):

```
gggg <- do.call(cbind, split(DF[2:3], DF$SysID))
xtable(gggg[,1:8])  
xtable(gggg[,9:16])
```